# Random 4D vector

Tags: vectors, random

I'd like to generate random 4D vectors. Their length must be 1.

A random 2D vector can be created like so:

```
vec[0] = sin(rand1 * PI * 2)
vec[1] = cos(rand1 * PI * 2)
```

A random 3D vector can be created like so:

```
vec[0] = sin(rand1 * PI * 2) * cos(rand2 * PI * 2);
vec[1] = cos(rand1 * PI * 2) * cos(rand2 * PI * 2);
vec[2] = sin(rand2 * PI * 2);
```

(rand1 and rand2 are random numbers between 0 and 1)

How can you make a random 4D vector in the same manner. Would it be possible to some how combine two 2D vectors?

Comment: "random" is not enough specification. What distribution?

Comment: If you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere you will see equations for setting up an $n$ dimensional vector.  Set $r=1$ and you could choose the angles uniformly from the ranges specified.

Comment: **Caution.** Even for the 3D method you gave, vectors chosen this way will not be distributed uniformly over the surface of the sphere. That is, you will generate more points per unit area near the poles than you will near the equator.

You don't say what you're using these for, so I don't know if that matters to you.

Comment: I use these for perlin noise. And I'm well aware of the ununiform distribution. I had a way with even distribution by creating a 2D vector, then rotating it in 3D, but it was inefficient for real time rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  One is given here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html

Summary: Generate $x_1,\dots,x_4$ using the standard normal distribution (often built-in) and normalize the vector $[x_1,\dots,x_4]$ to have unit length.

Answer (score 0):

Generalize from 3D:

```
vec[0] = sin(rand1 * PI * 2) * cos(rand2 * PI * 2) * cos(rand2 * PI * 2);
vec[1] = cos(rand1 * PI * 2) * cos(rand2 * PI * 2) * cos(rand2 * PI * 2);
vec[2] = sin(rand2 * PI * 2) * cos(rand3 * PI * 2);
vec[3] = sin(rand3 * PI * 2);
```

Comment: should be                                                                                               
`vec[0] = sin(rand1 * PI * 2) * cos(rand2 * PI * 2) * cos(rand3 * PI * 2);`
`vec[1] = cos(rand1 * PI * 2) * cos(rand2 * PI * 2) * cos(rand3 * PI * 2);`